# Consider a set $ \ A \ $ with $ \ n>0 \ $elements , $ \ \mathcal{O}=\{B \subset A: \ |B| \ \ is \ \ odd \} \ $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider a set $ \ A \ $ with $ \ n>0 \ $elements , $ \ \mathcal{O}=\{B \subset A: \ |B| \ \ is \ \ odd \} \ $ , $ \ \large \large \epsilon=\{B \subset A: \ |B| \ \ is \ \ even \} \ $.

Then which is true?

(i) $ \ |\mathcal{O}|< |\large \epsilon | \ $

(ii) $ \ |\mathcal{O} |=|\large \epsilon| \ $

(iii) $ \ | \mathcal{O} |>|\large \epsilon | \ $

**Answer:**

Let $ \ |A|=n \ $

Let $ P(A) \ $ denote the power set of $ \ A \ $, then

$  | P(A) |=2^n-1 \ $

Thus , we have

$ |\mathcal{O}|=\frac{2^n-2}{2} =  $ collection of subsets of $ \ A \ $ with odd number of elements

$ |\mathcal{\large \epsilon}|=\frac{2^n-2}{2} =  $ collection of subsets of $ \ A \ $ with even number of elements

Thus ,we see that

$ |\mathcal{O}|=\frac{2^n-2}{2} =|\large \epsilon | \ $

**Am I right ?**

Comment: You ended up with the correct conclusion based on completely faulty premises, unfortunately, The cardinality of the power set isn't $2^n - 1$, so everything after that is incorrect.

Comment: As a followup comment to point out a big red flag in the argument: $2^n - 1$ is odd, whereas the conclusion $|\mathcal{O}| = |\epsilon|$ implies that the size of the power set is even.

Comment: Maybe… [Google](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/176)?

Comment: How $ \ \mathcal{O}|=|\epsilon| \ $ implies the size of the power set is even ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that both sets have the same number of elements, but your argument is wrong, since $\bigl|\mathcal{P}(A)\bigr|=2^n$.

You can prove that $|\mathcal{O}|=|\varepsilon|$ by induction on $n$. If it is true for a cetain set $A$ and then you add a new element $k$ to $A$, let $\mathcal{O}'$ be the set of subsets of $A\cup\{k\}$ with an odd number of elements and let $\varepsilon'$ be the set of subsets of $A\cup\{k\}$ with an even number of elements. Then the elements of $\mathcal{O}'$ are the elements of $\mathcal{O}$ together with the elements of $\varepsilon$ after adding the element $k$ to each one of them. Therefore, $|\mathcal{O}'|=|\mathcal{O}|+|\varepsilon|$. By the same argument, $|\varepsilon'|=|\mathcal{O}|+|\varepsilon|$ too.

Answer (score 2):

That is not correct for several reasons.

1. $|P(A)|=2^n\neq 2^n-1$
2. $\dfrac{2^n-2}{2}+\dfrac{2^n-2}{2}=2^n-2$ so even if you were correct about the cardinality of the power set, you are saying that 1 set has a cardinality that is neither even nor odd?

How many subsets does the set have that have even cardinality? That would be:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \tfrac{n}{2} \rfloor} \dbinom{n}{2k}$$

How many have odd cardinality?

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \tfrac{n-1}{2} \rfloor} \dbinom{n}{2k+1}$$

You are trying to show those are equal. Not hard, but not trivial either.

Comment: Can it be proved using induction ?

Comment: That would be my recommendation.

Comment: How to show $ \sum_{k=0}^{\left [ \frac{m+1}{2} \right ]} \binom{m+1}{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\left [ \frac{m}{2} \right ]} \binom{m+1}{2k+1} \ $ when we know $ \  \sum_{k=0}^{\left [ \frac{m}{2} \right ]} \binom{m}{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\left [ \frac{m-1}{2} \right ]} \binom{m}{2k+1} \ $ ?

Comment: I would just use @JoseCarlosSantos's solution. That is a far more straightforward approach.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, $|P(A)|$ = $2^n$, not $2^{n-1}$. Now, if the size of $A$ is odd, we have the following bijection

$$
\Lambda:\mathcal{O} \longrightarrow \mathcal{E}
\\ B \longmapsto B^c
$$

with it's inverse being

$$
\Gamma:\mathcal{E} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}
\\ B \longmapsto B^c
$$
You can check that in effect, if $B$ has an odd amount of elements, $B^c$ will have an even amount, and viceversa. If that's not clear enough, recall that since we're assuming $|A|$ odd,

$$
|B| + |B^c| = |A| \equiv 1 \pmod{2}
$$

so these two must have different parity. Since we've constructed a bijection from $\mathcal{O}$ to $\mathcal{E}$, they have the same size (again, for $|A|$ odd). So what if $|A|$ is even?  Well, let's pick an arbitrary $a \in A$ and define

$$
\mathcal{O}_a = \{B \in \mathcal{O} : a \in B\} \\
\mathcal{O}_n = \{B \in \mathcal{O} : a \not \in B\} \\
\mathcal{E}_a = \{B \in \mathcal{E} : a \in B\} \\
\mathcal{E}_n = \{B \in \mathcal{E} : a \not \in B\} \\
$$

Since $\mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O}_a \sqcup \mathcal{O}_n$ and $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{E}_a \sqcup \mathcal{E}_n$, it will suffice to see that $|\mathcal{O}_a| = |\mathcal{E}_a|$ and $|\mathcal{O}_n| = |\mathcal{E}_n|$. The latter is immediate since $\mathcal{O}_n$ and $\mathcal{E}_n$ are the sets of odd and even subsets of $A \setminus \{a\}$ which has now odd size. As for $|\mathcal{O}_a| = |\mathcal{E}_a|$, this is because

$$
|\mathcal{O}_a| = |\mathcal{E}_n| = |\mathcal{O}_n| = |\mathcal{E}_a|
$$

via the bijections

$$
\alpha : \mathcal{O}_a \longrightarrow \mathcal{E}_n
\\ \quad \quad B \mapsto B\setminus \{a\}
$$

and

$$
\beta : \mathcal{E}_a \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_n
\\ \quad \quad B \mapsto B\setminus \{a\}
$$